# Assigning Global Picklist Values to recordtypes from Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, global-picklist

I need to assign some newly created global picklist values to some record types in my application via Metadata API only.

I have referred some online tutorials and got to know that this feature is not available via Metadata API yet.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you post a reference to those online tutorials?

Comment: Are you asking about Global Value Sets (that you define in your application) or Standard Value Sets (for standard picklists)? Either way, it should be possible, but may be more complicated than you expect.